# Test presence of javascript code/snippet with rspec capybara (Rails 4)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, capybara

I'd like to create a test to make sure my third party tools (js scripts) are present (for example, to make sure nobody in the team removed it by accident!)

Here are 2 javascript third party tool that are loaded on my homepage view whose presence i'd like to test:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var clicky_site_ids = clicky_site_ids || [];
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
(function() {
  var s = document.createElement('script');
  s.type = 'text/javascript';
  s.async = true;
  s.src = '//static.getclicky.com/js';
  ( document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0] ).appendChild( s );
})();
</script>

<script src="//src.melvinize.io/r.js"></script>
```

Here are my rspec test (I'm using Capybara with webkit driver)

```
describe "third party tools are present inside source code", js: true do  

    it 'should have js trackings' do
      visit(root_path)
      all('script').find { |s| s[:src].match /getclicky\.js$/ }.should_not be_nil
      all('script').find ("//static.getclicky.com/js").should_not be_nil

      all('script').find ("//src.melvinize.io/r.js").should_not be_nil
    end 

  end
```

My test does not work as it always pass (!), but I'm a rookie with this kind of tests using regular expressions and I'm not even sure that's the right way to do it.

Comment: I would suggest that you focus on testing the end result of your javascript rather than attempt to verify the presence of the code. Using a version control system such as Git will allow you to keep track of what others might do to your source. So, if the javascript results in the placement of a link, button or test, test for the presence of the link, button or text with Rspec/Capybara. This would, de facto, verify the presence of your javascript with the additional benefit of testing the expected behavior from the users perspective.

Comment: @DanCrews thanks for the answer but it doesn't meet my needs: i'm not using a javascript that has obvious impact on a color or a link  (in which case what you advice would work). The javascript scripts i want to make sure are present are Clicky (like google analytics) so it only runs on the background to count the views and clicks and the other one is like respond.js (it adds media queries capabilities for ie8) so in both cases i can't test their "output", i'd just like to find a regular expression checking it's still in the source code (to complement of course our source code human checks)